# Connecting language switch button to embedded url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, internationalization, tableau-api

I have implemented i18n into my app which is embedding tableau dashboards and i want the button which changes languages to change the url of the tableau embedd.
So if French is selected, an FR will be added to the url and if English is selected it will disappear

This is Navbar.js where the language switch button is and it encompasses the tableau embeddment:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";
import Logout from "./Icons/Logout.svg";







import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';








//Navbar function
function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Operational Overview');
  const location = useLocation();
  

  //i18n

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const lngs = {
    en: {nativeName: 'English'},
    fr: {nativeName: 'French'}
  };
  
  

  

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
  
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
      return (true)
    } )

  };

  const userConfigPageTitle = (path) => {
    setPageName("User Information");

  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 


  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="criminal-records">{t("navbar.criminalRecords")}</div> 

          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{t("navbar." + pageName)}</h1></div>

        <div className="language-component"> 
        <div>
          {Object.keys(lngs).map((lng) => (
            <button key={lng} style={{ fontWeight: i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng ? 'bold' : 'normal' }} type="submit" onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage(lng)}>
              {lngs[lng].nativeName}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
       
    
        
        

        </div>



          <Link to='userconfig' onClick={userConfigPageTitle}>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          </Link>
        
     
          <Link to='/' className="logout-button">
          <div className="right-side">
            <img className="logoutIcon" src={Logout} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="logoutButton">{t("navbar.logout")}</div> 
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
        
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{t("navbar." + item.title)}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

And this is one of the Tableau views (Finance.js):

```
import React from 'react'
import "../App.css"
import TableauView from 'insights-tableau';

function Finance() {
  return(<div className='MainDashboard'>
    <div className='dashboard-container'>
    <TableauView src="https://isr-tableau/views/Demo/Finance" toolbar="hidden" />
    </div>
    </div> )
}

export default Finance
```

And this is index.js to undertand the structure of the app:

```
const AppLayout = () => {


  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
  </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

}








const router = createBrowserRouter([
  
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <LoginScreen />
  },
  
  
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "monitoringoverview",
        element: <MonitoringOverview />,
      },
  
      {
        path: "performancequality",
        element: <PerformanceQuality />,
      },

      {
        path: "finance",
        element: <Finance />,
      },
      {
        path: "simulation",
        element: <Simulation />,
      },
      {
        path: 'userconfig',
        element: <UserConfig />
      },
      {
        path: 'fraud',
        element: <Fraud />
      },


      
    ],
  },
]);



createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  
);
```

Comment: what issues are you facing? Btw, if you use map function you should return statement for it to work.